# Getting MYSQL error from statement

Tags: php, mysql

How can I get the error to show from my MYSQL Statement below or is there a better way to write the below with PDO or similar:

**Code:**

```
$mysqlFiles = "SELECT campaign_image, optout_image FROM campaigns WHERE id = '$campaign_id'";

while($data = mysql_fetch_assoc($mysqlFiles));
{
    $imageNames[] = $data;
}
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php ? am not quite grasping here. Are you trying to deliberately cause an error?

Comment: You'll need to execute your query before fetching data. See examples for [`mysql_query()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php). Also, yes, I highly recommend using MySQLi or PDO.

Comment: What exactly do you want. It is not very clear to me. Errors are probably written to the place defined by your php.ini

Comment: You did not even execute  the query!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a good bit incorrect with your code.

1. For starters, you're using [`mysql_fetch_assoc`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php) on a string, not a resource.
2. Your SQL is vulnerable to SQL injection.  You should be using [prepared statements](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/477563).
3. The `mysql_*` functions are deprecated.  You should be using the [`mysqli_*`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) functions.

Once you've corrected those issues, you can view error messages use [`mysqli_error`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php).

Comment: You gota be kidin me. You accepted this as an answer over the other one?

Answer (score 0):

Use this (source: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php):

```
mysql_error ($mysqlconnection);
```

Answer (score 0):

*Firstly...* in this line of code:

```
while($data = mysql_fetch_assoc($mysqlFiles));
                                             ^ end of statement, stops the process.
```

- Notice the semi-colon at the end there?

*Believe it or not,* that is considered as valid syntax (and won't throw an error because of it), **BUT**... is also ending your statement and will not process `{ $imageNames[] = $data; }`.

Whether the query is successful or not, it will still STOP right there.

Remove it

```
while($data = mysql_fetch_assoc($mysqlFiles))
```

Reference on semi-colon:

- http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.instruction-separation.php

> *"As in C or Perl, PHP requires instructions to be **terminated** with a semicolon at the end of each statement. The closing tag of a block of PHP code automatically implies a semicolon; you do not need to have a semicolon terminating the last line of a PHP block. The closing tag for the block will include the immediately trailing newline if one is present."*

If you want to catch potential errors, use `mysql_error()` against your query

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php

Something else I noticed is that you're **not "querying"** with `mysql_query()`.

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

so your code will never result in a successful query along with what's already been said.

Example from the manual:

```
$query = sprintf("SELECT firstname, lastname, address, age FROM friends 
    WHERE firstname='%s' AND lastname='%s'",
    mysql_real_escape_string($firstname),
    mysql_real_escape_string($lastname));

// Perform Query
$result = mysql_query($query);
```

Example from http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo $row["userid"];
    echo $row["fullname"];
    echo $row["userstatus"];
}
```

If the following were coded as such and with the semi-colon, it would not process anything inside `{...}`:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)); {
                                    //   ^ semi-colon terminator similar to yours
    echo $row["userid"];
    echo $row["fullname"];
    echo $row["userstatus"];
}
```

Comment: I hope this will serve for somebody. I thought I explained this rather well, unless I didn't grasp the question.